# YouTube embeded video will not resize (only full screen responsive)

Tags: embed, youtube

I am running Headway theme in the latest version of WP.  I embed the code below although it ignores the youtube embed size and renders full width on the front end.

Code:

Comment: The theme is using the fit vids javascript library which makes various types of videos responsive. Please contact the authors of the Headway theme to see if there is a way to disable this functionality for particular videos. Unfortunately, third party themes and plugins are out of scope here on WPSE.

Comment: Thanks.  Found it.  There is a check box in the Headway backend.  It worked.

Answer (score 1):

There is a check box in the Headway backend. Unticked it - and it worked. Embedded youtube video will now resize with iframe size code.  Thanks Dave Romsey